# git ignore directories "build" and all their contents but not "build.xml"

Tags: git, ant, gitignore

I am using **git** in a project where **Ant** is the build system.
Since I do not wish to add "build" directories to **git** but need to add **build.xml** files I have resorted to the following two lines in my **.gitignore** files:

```
build/
!build.xml
```

Is there a better / more concise way ?

**UPDATE:**
turns out **build.xml** was ignored due to a **.gitignore** in a directory higher up the path. Once that was removed, **build/** correctly ignores only the build folder, not the **build.xml** file beside it.

Comment: why don't you like this way? it's pretty clear. ignore build/ except build.xml (though it's better be !build/build.xml)

Comment: I just want git to ignore the build folder but include under version control the build.xml file that sits alongside it (not inside it).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No, there is no better way, that's pretty much the way to do it. To be precise,

```
build/*
!build/build.xml
```

As you want to have the folder and ignore all other files in it except build.xml.

Note though that common directory layout for Ant is that build.xml is in the app root folder, whereas build folder only contains files created during build. See further rationale in, for example, [here](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/994991/Building-with-Ant-Directory-Structure.htm).

---

Edit. if you actually have build.xml in the app root, just

```
build
```

in .gitignore should be enough. However, it should be noted it only applies to detecting new entries, if you've already committed something to git, you'll have to remove that yourself.

Comment: Yeah, that's my case, the build folder only contains build artifacts, the build.xml file sits at the root, not inside the build folder.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus ok, so wouldn't just `build/*` entry then be enough?

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus it really shouldn't do that - the only exception is that if those files have already been added before .gitignore was in place. Just tested, and none of build/, build/* and build affect build.xml.

Answer (score 2):

You can also just ignore /build/, that will ignore only the folder called build, no files.

Answer (score 2):

You can also ignore any folder starts with build like so:

```
**/.build
**/build
```